# Should I set the cell on cellForItemAtIndexPath or willDisplayCell?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

[this page](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/perfect-smooth-scrolling-in-uitableviews-fd609d5275a5#.gl679xgad) that talks about tricks to smooth table view scrolling, says the table view cells should be drawn not on `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` but rather on `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`.

I have tried that approach on  and I see no difference on my initial tests. Is there any truth about that?

should I really use `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` to create the cell, set thumbnails, texts, etc. instead of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: I always use cellForRowAtIndexPath but, maybe is right, and maybe your test need to be more performance hard for your table view, i will study this article and maybe learn something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes its true that **both** **perform** the **same function** **but** use `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for tableview where **datasource** has to be implemented as `cellForRowAtIndexPath` **works fast** and you must return reused cell identifiers quickly. This is a method of datasource of tableview

`tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath` is a method of delegate & not datasource. This method is called exactly before loading cells in `UITableView` bounds.